# How to limit iTunes App Store "Requirements" listing?

Tags: xcode, ios, app-store, itunes-store

The iTunes AppStore auto generates some listings on its published pages.  One of them is "Requirements:" and shows the devices that this app is compatible with.  iPod, iPhone or iPad etc.

QUESTION: Where is this REQUIREMENTS listing set during the build process?

I have submitted an app that I 'thought' was properly configured because the Xcode settings for iPhone and NOT iPhone/iPad.  But apparently this is either broken or I am totally confused as to where this is set and how its created on the AppStore.

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: I will never understand why people want to artificially limit the range of supported devices.

Comment: not my choice - this is choice of the party we developed the apps for...

Answer (score 2):

If you create an app that is iPod/iPhone only, it will still run on an iPad, just not as an iPad native app. That is to say, an iPhone/iPod-only app will run in an iPhone-sized window on an iPad. I do not think that you can say you want your iPhone app NOT to run on iPad.

When you select iPhone/iPad for your app type in Xcode, that is telling Apple and iTunes that your app binary is a universal app -- built for both platforms.

Comment: yes but there is a REQUIREMENTS field in the appstore that shows your compatible with types.  I've been asked to REMOVE the iPad compatability... and even tho I did not set iPad compatible from Xcode settings ( I chose iPhone for Target device setting NOT iPhone/iPad ) - it still shows as iPad compatible in the iTunes app store.  Im trying to find out where this "Requirements" blurb is set...is this is iTunes connect somewhere? or is this pulled from the plist and then placed into iTunes?

Comment: also there IS a key called: UIDeviceFamily that lets you set 1
(Default) The application runs on iPhone and iPod touch devices.
2
The application runs on iPad devices.  ( Im trying to find the setting that changes the iTunes APPSTORE listing for Requirements as well )

Comment: My belief is that you cannot change this. The fact that an iPad can run an app that is for iPhone only, makes the app iPad compatible. This is different than iPad *native* (which is the iPhone/iPad setting you referred to) which means it's a universal app. I have several apps on the App Store, none of which were built for iPad, but they all appear as iPad compatible in the store.

Comment: yes this is a confusing subject as you can see...try looking at this key - I think this is where you can actually limit it.  But Im still looking for where it gets pulled and posted for the AppStore field called "Requirements"

Comment: Look at the key `UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities`. You can include this in your Info.plist as a dictionary, and include, among other things, the features you want to explicitly require OR disallow. Perhaps if you disallow the ARM architecture specific to iPad, that will achieve the goal. Unfortunately, that may also exclude certain iPhone devices too... You could require telephony, which would certainly exclude iPad, but also iPod. If that's ok, this may be the trick!

Comment: I looked at this as well ( this was what was mentioned to me as the way to do this ) - but its really just restricting by feature not by device family. We don't want to exclude iPodTouch... so that won't work.  Also iPad has same ARM as iPhone 4 yes? So can't do that...

Comment: Yeah, I had the same thought. Was it the same person who said "exclude iPad" that suggested UIDeviceRequiredCapabilities as the way to do it? :-)

Comment: yea it seems they may have been given the wrong info as to how to do this... and so far I have not found the appropriate way to do this - nor do I know where the requirements blurb on the AppStore is set!  Because its not settable in submitting an app thru iTunesConnect ( just verified by a friend submitting to appStore ).  So Im still totally unclear as to where this blurb is getting its generated info from.

Comment: I suspect the "Requirements" info is in fact collected from several different items in the Info.plist and/or build settings. Unfortunately, the exact list is apparently a mystery. Have you tried the Apple Developer Forums?

Answer (score 2):

may be it's done by apple reviewers according to this guidelines limitation

App Store Review Guidelines:
2.10
iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution
... or else it will be rejected.

Comment: this may be the right answer... Im waiting to see what Apple's official response is.  If this is the case then you cannot have a deployment to appstore that removes ONLY iPads from its requirements listing... this combo is not possible from the available set of plist settings discussed so far!

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem? When you start a project you get to choose whether its for iPhone or iPad or both. When you submit it to apple this is also checked against your iOS build version and other things (normally though if there's a conflict it'll let you know before submission - eg: if you haven't included the iPad icons and your app says that its for iPad too).

In XCode4 theres a nice handy interface now that you can use. If you select your project in the left hand pane and click on your main target in the main window you can select the iOS application targets that your app is for.

Comment: I set 'Target Device' in Xcode to iPhone ( not to iPhone/iPad ) - but the text field in AppStore still showed iPad compatible ( even tho the store does not list it as an iPad app... its still installable ).  This leads me to believe there are multiple places where this stuff is set and has led to some inconsistency between what I set and what the store shows and allows.

Answer (score 0):

In your Project settings Version, Device and Deployment Target are where the iTunes *Requirements* come from. If you choose only **iPhone**, then your requirements will inlcude iPod touch.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the answer you are looking for:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html